# Modify Object in DynamoDB without conflicts in Lambda function

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have example Objects of this interface:

```TS
interface Car{
id: Number;
name: String;
tires: Wheel[]
}

interface Wheel{
id: Number;
name: String;
radius: Number;
}
```

I need to store these Car Objects in DynamoDB and want to access and modify them from AWS Lambda functions called by AWS API-Gateway. I.e. add wheels, modify wheels, add new cars etc with multiple useres doing so in parallel from an API. As far as I understand there is nothing ORM-Like that can help me. I asume i would store the root object car as record with all its sub objects.

As far as I understand i have to get the entire object from dynamoDB, change it within the lambda function and replace it in dynamoDB. But if two users make two seperate changes on one object at the same time they would override each other and some changes would get lost?
How do i ensure parallel editing of objects without the danger of losing changes?

Answer (score 0):

UpdateItem API only upserts, never overwrites. So if each user called UpdateItem the final image of the item will contain all users updates, none will be missed and none overwritten.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html

If you have a requirement that you read the item first and then make updates then you require optimistic locking which is easy to implement using condition expressions or if you use some of the higher level clients in Java or .Net then it's built in automatically using annotations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html